# Check if templated member function exists SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

Following issue:
I want to check whether a templated method is existing or not, herefore I have adapted the examples given here:
[Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

#define CHECK4_MEMBER_FUNC(RETTYPE,FUNCTION,...) \
template <class ClassType> \
class CIfCheck_##FUNCTION \
{\
private: \
    template <class MemberPointerType> \
    static std::true_type testSignature(RETTYPE (MemberPointerType::*)(__VA_ARGS__)); \
\
    template <class MemberPointerType> \
    static std::false_type testExistence(...); \
   \
    template <class MemberPointerType> \
    static decltype(testSignature(&MemberPointerType::FUNCTION)) testExistence(std::nullptr_t); \
public: \
    using type = decltype(testExistence<ClassType>(nullptr));\
    static const bool value = type::value; \
};


    class Bla
    {
    public:
        template <typename SomeType>
        bool init(SomeType someValue)
        {
            ///
            return true;
        }

        void exec()
        {
            return;
        }
    };

    CHECK4_MEMBER_FUNC(bool, init, int);
    CHECK4_MEMBER_FUNC(void, exec, void);

int main()
{
  Bla blaObj;
  blaObj.init<int>(2);
  static_assert(CIfCheck_exec<Bla>::value, "no exec");
  static_assert(CIfCheck_init<Bla>::value, "no init");

  return 0;
}
```

but unfortunately the `static_assert()` is triggered for `init()` (as the specialization is probably evaluated at a later time as the object is being instantiated in `main()`) .

I tried with explicit member-specialization, but it is still failing:

```
template<>
bool Bla::init<int>(int item)
{
    int temp = item*2; // do with item something
    return false;
}
```

P.S.: side-question (probably another question topic would make more sense:

```
std::false_type testExistence(...);
```

Why exactly do I have to pass an argument here? If I remove the variadic argument `...` option (and `nullptr` and `nullptr_t`), the compiler errors due to ambiguous existence of `testExistence()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but unfortunately the static_assert is triggered for init (as the specialization is probably evaluated at a later time as the object is being instantiated in main())

Not exactly.

The problem is that `init()` is a template method, so when you write

```
decltype(testSignature(&MemberPointerType::FUNCTION))
```

no pointer is selected because the compiler can't select the right method.

You can try with

```
decltype(testSignature(&MemberPointerType::template FUNCTION<__VA_ARGS__>))
```

but now doesn't works for `exec()` that isn't a template method

To works with both template and non-template method... not simple passing trough a variadic macro because the variadic part can't be empty... but I propose something as follows

```
template <typename...>
struct wrap
 { };

#define CHECK4_MEMBER_FUNC(RETTYPE,FUN,...) \
template <class ClassType> \
class CIfCheck_##FUN \
{\
private: \
    template <typename MPT> \
    static auto testSig (wrap<void>) \
       -> std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<MPT>().FUN()),\
                       RETTYPE>; \
    \
    template <typename MPT, typename ... As> \
    static auto testSig (wrap<As...>) \
       -> std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<MPT>().FUN(std::declval<As>()...)), \
                       RETTYPE>; \
    \
    template <typename...> \
    static std::false_type testSig (...);\
    \
public: \
    using type = decltype(testSig<ClassType>(wrap<__VA_ARGS__>{}));\
    static const bool value = type::value; \
};
```

Observe that I've added a `wrap` structure to wrap template parameter types; usually is used `std::tuple` but, in this case, we need `wrap<void>` because `std::tuple<void>` gives error.

Observe also that my solution is different from another point of view (and can be better or worse, according your specific needs): your solution check if is present a method with the exactly signature; my solution check if is present a method that is callable with a given list of arguments.

Concrete example: suppose that there is a `Bla::foo()` method that accept a `long` value

```
    void foo (long)
     { }
```

With your solution, if you check for an `int` parameter

```
CHECK4_MEMBER_FUNC(void, foo, int);

static_assert( false == CIfCheck_foo<Bla>::value, "no foo with int");
```

you get a `false` value from `CIfCheck_foo` because there isn't in `Bla` a method `foo` of type `void(&BLA::*)(int)` (there is a `void(&BLA::*)(long)` that is different).

With my method you get a **`true`** value from `CIfCheck_foo` because the `foo(long)` accept also a `int` value (and the returned type is `void`).

---

> std::false_type testExistence(...);
>
> Why exactly do I have to pass an argument here? If I remove the variadic argument `...` option (and `nullptr` and `nullptr_t`), the compiler errors due to ambiguous existence of `testExistence()`.

That `testExistence()`, as

```
    template <typename...> \
    static std::false_type testSig (...);\
```

is the second choice.

I mean... when you macro call `testExistence()` inside `decltype()`

```
decltype(testExistence<ClassType>(nullptr));
```

or my macro call `testSig()` inside `decltype()`

```
decltype(testSig<ClassType>(wrap<__VA_ARGS__>{}));
```

call that functions with an argument (`nullptr` or `wrap<__VA_ARGS__>{}`).

When the first choice is available (when is present a `RETTYPE (MemberPointerType::*)(__VA_ARGS__)` in your case, when is callable a method with the required arguments in my example), the compiler choose that version and return `std::true_type` (or `std::is_same` in my code).

But when the first choice isn't available?

Second choices, the versions returning `std::false`, are required. But the call is with an argument. The ellipsis here is the old C-style variadic argument list and accept zero or more arguments, so accept also one argument.

If you remove the ellipsis (`...`), the second choices can't accept an argument anymore (become zero arguments functions) and you get a compilation error because the compiler doesn't find a second choice function compatible with an argument.

Comment: I am not directly allowed to use std::, so have to write my own `declval` implementation, but this works. Can you help me in understanding `static std::false_type testSig (...);` (was also part of the question above)

Comment: @mbed_dev - answer improved: new part starts with "Observe also that".